# How bootstrap setarg_with_occurs_check/3 in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, occurs-check

How would one go about and bootstrap `setarg_with_occurs_check/3` in
Prolog. It seems Prolog has two ways to create cyclic data structures.
Not only unification can do that, but also setarg/3:

```
/* SWI-Prolog 8.3.26 */
?- X = f(X).
X = f(X).

?- X = f(0), setarg(1,X,X).
X = f(X).
```

Lets say I want the analogue of `unify_with_occurs_check/2` for
`setarg/3`. How would one go about and implement the same?

(BTW In some Prolog systems setarg/3 sometimes goes by the
name change_arg/3, and some even don't have it at all)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the ISO predicate [`acyclic_term/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=acyclic_term/1). Thus, in SWI-Prolog, you can define:

```
setarg_with_occurs_check(Arg, Term, Value) :-
    setarg(Arg, Term, Value),
    acyclic_term(Term).
```

Examples:

```
?- X = f(0), setarg_with_occurs_check(1,X,Y).
X = f(Y).

?- X = f(0), setarg_with_occurs_check(1,X,X).
false.

?- X = f(X), Y = g(Z), setarg_with_occurs_check(1,Y,X).
false.
```